# c++ catch catch bad_alloc and delete pointer

Tags: c++, exception, pointers

i have the following function and my problem is that i can't delete temp in the catch because it says that temp is undeclared but i don't understand why? any help is appreciated.

```
List_Node*List::copy(const List_Node*  list) 
{
    if(list == nullptr) 
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            List_Node* temp = new List_Node(list -> value_);
            temp -> next_ = copy(list -> next_);
            return temp;
        }
    catch (bad_alloc& )
    {
      delete temp;   
        throw;
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Everything inside a pair of `{` and `}` is local variable. `temp` is declared inside `try {}`, which is not visible inside `catch{}`.

Comment: Because it's in a different scope...

Comment: What are you trying to delete? If `bad_alloc` have been raised by new, then the allocation failed and you have nothing to delete.

Comment: He is probably trying to catch `bad_alloc` from the recursive `copy`, and delete all previous allocated good pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision can be like this:

```
List_Node*List::copy(const List_Node*  list) 
{
    if(list == nullptr) 
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        List_Node* temp = 0;
        try
        {
            temp = new List_Node(list -> value_);
            temp -> next_ = copy(list -> next_);
            return temp;
        }
    catch (bad_alloc& )
    {
      delete temp;   
        throw;
    }
 }

}
```

Or use auto-ptr in the first case.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` shouldn't be used, use `std::unique_ptr` instead.

Comment: I mean auto-ptr in common sense (auto_ptr in C++98, unique_ptr in C++11).